# Tomcat 7 and AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer are not working together

Tags: java, spring-security, tomcat7, servlet-3.0

I was following this [article](http://blog.springsource.org/2013/07/03/spring-security-java-config-preview-web-security/) to try a basic http-auth without the use of a web.xml

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.41 and those are my dependencies on gradle:

```
  ext.springVersion =  "3.2.1.RELEASE"
  compile "org.springframework:spring-jdbc:$springVersion",
          "org.springframework:spring-context:$springVersion",
          "org.springframework:spring-web:$springVersion",
          "org.springframework:spring-webmvc:$springVersion",
          "org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.0.M2",
          "org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.0.M2",
          "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.0.M2",
```

According to the tutorial I defined the following

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeUrls().antMatchers("/").hasRole("USER")
                .and().httpBasic();
    }

}
```

then added that class to the initializer like this:

```
@Order(1)
public class ServletConfiguration extends
        AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { SecurityConfiguration.class };
        // return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { AppConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

//  @Override
//  protected Dynamic registerServletFilter(ServletContext servletContext,
//          Filter filter) {
//      Dynamic securityFilter = servletContext.addFilter(
//              "springSecurityFilterChain", DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
//      securityFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(
//              EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
//      return securityFilter;
//  }

}
```

and finally added a class to inizialize the springSecurityFilterChain:

```
@Order(2)
public class SecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer  {
@Override
protected void afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    System.out.println("afterSpringSecurityFilterChain");
    super.afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
}
}
```

But I'm always getting this error:

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.jndi.JndiPropertySource - JNDI lookup for name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] threw NamingException with message: Name [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [spring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain].. Returning null.
Jul 11, 2013 9:22:24 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter springSecurityFilterChain
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined
```

I don't why though, because when I go debugging the server initialization, actually these two methods are called:

```
@Override
public final void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
        throws ServletException {
    if(enableHttpSessionEventPublisher()) {
        servletContext.addListener(HttpSessionEventPublisher.class);
    }
    insertSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
    afterSpringSecurityFilterChain(servletContext);
}
```

then

```
private void insertSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    String filterName = "springSecurityFilterChain";
    DelegatingFilterProxy springSecurityFilterChain = new DelegatingFilterProxy(filterName);
    String contextAttribute = getWebApplicationContextAttribute();
    if(contextAttribute != null) {
        springSecurityFilterChain.setContextAttribute(contextAttribute);
    }
    registerFilter(servletContext, true, filterName, springSecurityFilterChain);
}
```

So actually the filter gets created. But then it gets lost somewhere.

I tried to play with `@Order`, but that was doing nothing so I tried to register `springSecurityFilterChain` using the `registerServletFilter` method but I'm not getting any http-auth request authentication.
And also `SecurityConfiguration` doens't even get loaded.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SecurityInitializer creates the DelegatingFilterProxy which is used to look up a bean by the name of springSecurityFilterChain. The springSecurityFilterChain is created using @EnableWebSecurity. The problem is that you are missing the `@Configuration` annotation (without it the Root ApplicationContext is not even going to try to load the SecurityConfiguration). Specifically you want to do the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

A few additional things to point out:

- You do not need to use the `@Order` because you are not adding any other Filters
- The only URL you have secured is the context root (i.e. /).
- You will want to be aware of a bug with httpBasic() that is discussed on [need spring security java config example showing basic auth only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559030/need-spring-security-java-config-example-showing-basic-auth-only)
- UPDATE: I should have also pointed out that I have already logged [SPR-10660](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10660) to support `@Enable*` annotations without having `@Configuration` on them. After that is resolved, your issue would magically go away.

Comment: Thank you very much! And I read it more times. Although this question was useful to know about the bug. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem @dierre :) Note I added an update referring to another JIRA that once resolved would have fixed this issue for you.

Comment: I see that SPR-10660 is still unresolved after 2.5 years.

Comment: @DerekMahar This was actually resolved as another issue (see updates to the issue). Have you tried with Spring 4.0+?

Comment: No, I haven't tried this with Spring 4.0+.  Actually, I've never encountered this issue!  I was just passing by while searching for a solution to another issue where a Spring MVC and Security application was instantiating the same beans twice.  I figured out how to resolve this by better understanding how `@ComponentScan` works and the relationship between the root and dispatcher contexts in Spring MVC. Not really related to the issue here. In any case, thank you for resolving SPR-10660.