# Spring Security 3.2 setting authenticationEntryPoint in HttpSecurity has no effect (Java-Config)

Tags: spring-security

I want to convert spring security configuration from xml to java config.
Is't nearly done, the last issue is the AuthenticationEntryPoint. The settings of it in HttpSecurity will be ignored.

I use Spring security 3.2.0.M2

*Snipped of SecurityConfig.class*

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterAfter(httpPayloadFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(httpRestLoginFilter(), SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .authorizeUrls()
                .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers("/secure/clientident/**").hasRole("REQUESTVALID")
                .and()
            .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint());
    }

@Bean
    public DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint() {

        ELRequestMatcher matcher = new ELRequestMatcher("hasHeader('user-agent', 'Mozilla') or " +
                "hasHeader('user-agent', 'Chromium') or " +
                "hasHeader('user-agent', 'Chrome') or " +
                "hasHeader('user-agent', 'Safari')");


        LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint> map = 
                new LinkedHashMap<RequestMatcher, AuthenticationEntryPoint>();
        map.put(matcher, new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint());

        DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint = new DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint(map);
        delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint.setDefaultEntryPoint(new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint());


        return delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }
```

I always get the "HTTP 403" (guess Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint) on client side.
I also have tried an easier config without delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint like.

```
.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint())
```

this will not work too.
Has anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong?

***Add:***
Should have locked better. Found another post about this issue.
[need spring security java config example showing basic auth only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559030/need-spring-security-java-config-example-showing-basic-auth-only/17571710#17571710) 
A Ticket [SEC-2198](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2198) has also been placed.

current workaround.

```
.exceptionHandling()
   .authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint())
   .and()
.httpBasic();
```