# Spring Security test returns 401 (unauthorized)

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

In this documentation [Spring Security MVC Test](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test-mockmvc.html) it is described how to test secured ressources with Spring Security. I followed all the steps provided but accessing a protected ressource still returns the error code 401 (unauthorized).

Here is my test class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebAppConfiguration
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context)
            .defaultRequest(
                    get("/api/users/1")
                            .with(user("test@test.com").password("test"))
                            .with(httpBasic("sc68", "adminpass"))
            )
            .apply(springSecurity())
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testUnprotectedResource() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/articles"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testProtectedResource() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/users/1"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

My ResourceServerConfiguration:

```
@Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/users/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/articles").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and(    )
            .csrf().disable()
}
```

If you want to take a look at the whole project you can find it [here](https://github.com/p-engelkes/sc68_backend). I already tried different test runners and everything described in the tutorial but I can not find a solution how to get an authenticated user during tests.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you should have both `user()` and `httpBasic()`. `user()` is for form-based authentication, and will create a SecurityContext with a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken. `httpBasic` will create a the base64 encoded Authentication header.

You security configuration seems to be missing the `httpBasic()` configuration, it looks to me like there is no security mechanism configured, just a number of matchers. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559030/need-spring-security-java-config-example-showing-basic-auth-only)

Comment: I have the basic authentication in my AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter. From my Angular App I can receive my AccessToken via this URL: http://localhost:8081/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=sc68&username=test@test.com&password=test"